/tools/cmd/deadcode false positive functions call in test files
I'm using the command deadcode https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/tools@v0.28.0/cmd/deadcode for finding deadcode in my code base but I have some issues with the test files.
I'm using this command
deadcode -test ./services/core/...
and as output I have the list of all unused functions.
The problem is that some of the unused functions are actually used and called by some test in _test.go files, so are not unused.
I have also tried to use the -filter flag
deadcode -test -filter=./services/... ./services/core/...
but it does not produce any output
Do someone know how to solve this issue?
Ty so much

You need to provide a [mre] to demonstrate what the problem is, what the output that it is reporting. You said this is a problem with test files, but are the functions actually in the test files?
